# Which method is better including files?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a file inside my plugin called `foo_widget.php`

Inside this file, I want to include a file called `foo_widget_class.php`

This works:

```
include('foo_widget_class.php');
```

also this works:

```
include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'foo_widget_class.php');
```

also this works

```
 include(__DIR__.'/foo_widget_class.php');
```

Which one is the better approach and why?

Comment: second-one is better in the sense that it has less chance of wrong file path

Comment: What about `include(__DIR__.'/foo_widget_class.php');`?

Comment: You should also use `require` instead of `include`.

Comment: why require instead of include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same different is you passing Absolute and Relative URLs